# Is there a way to reload a screen in React-Native one time after it loads?

Tags: react-native, websocket

I have a react native screen with a joystick component I made but on first load up the joystick doesn't work as intended but works perfectly fine when page is reloaded. Is there any way to set it to reload once quickly one time when it opens?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a bug in your code. You should try to locate the issue and resolve it. However, you could use useEffect() to call a state update as a temporary solution:

```js
const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   setReload(true)
}, []) // <- no dependencies
```